# wkhtmltopdf and multiple pages

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

i am trying to convert html pages like this one [click here](http://vz275.worldserver.net/converter/pdf/52040/HandangoOverview.php)
into a pdf. when i use wkhtmltopdf i ve get this result [click here](http://vz275.worldserver.net/converter/pdf/52040/HandangoOverview.pdf)

the options i ve used are:
 `xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -s A4 --zoom 1.0 -d 96`

tried also some others but all with a crappy result.

maybe someone of you had the same problem and found a solution. would be nice if someone could help me with this.

kind regards

nowkin

Answer (score 0):

I have had very good luck generating properly formatted PDF files via PHP with the FPDF class: [www.fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org)

I don't know if that solution fits your project, but I've always been able easily follow the documentation to adjust my output to avoid issues like you are currently experiencing.